# How to convert 1/1/1300 date to datetime value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a scenario where i have date value like 1/1/1300 and i want to convert it to datetime object for comparison purposes. In Sql Server i use datetime2 for this date and it works perfect but i dont know how to convert it to datetime2 in C#? Im using .Net 4

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("1/1/1300", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or use [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) if the date could be in a wrong format or represent an invalid date:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("1/1/1300", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // parsing was successful => you could use the date here
}
```

Comment: I try Datetime.ParseExact in a linq query and it gives me this error. Method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' has no supported translation to SQL

Answer (score 0):

There is no DateTime2 in C#, just DateTime:

```
string dateString = "1/1/1300";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is converting `datetime2` SQL data type to .NET data type, check this answer:

[Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type results out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type)

It seems to suggest that the type is same `DateTime` though, the snippet in the answer:

```
new DataColumn("myDate", typeof(DateTime))
```

I assume if you are using a DataReader, you can treat the value as `DateTime` also,  or maybe a `DateTimeOFfset` if `DateTime`.

If you are using an ORM, it will depend on the ORM used. You might need to specify how you access your database if this still doesn't help.