# how to cast datetime2 as datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, ssis

I'm trying to convert datetime2 to datetime in order to create a standard between different sources using only SQL or SSIS
Take the following SQL query as example:

```
SELECT CAST(offer_start_date AS timestamp)
FROM [ODS].[macaclient_offers]
```

I get the following error:
'Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to timestamp is not allowed.'

Furthermore, I did managed to convert datetime2 into date using a simple cast.

What is the right way to convert datetime2 to datetime using SQL Server 2008 or SSIS?

gilibi

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-sharp-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type?

Comment: I have, but I can't use C# in the case

Comment: You've edited the query, but obviously the error message is no longer correct - do you still *have* an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to accomplish that using a SSIS data conversion component.
I found out that I can use either DT_DBTIME2 or DT_DBTIME

Thanks for everyone who helped

Answer (score 11):

You are casting to `timestamp` in your code. Change to `datetime`.

```
SELECT CAST(offer_start_date AS datetime) FROM [ODS].[macaclient_offers]
```

Comment: I copied the wrong query. it should be the same as you suggested but this doesn't work

Comment: Strange. It works just fine in my tests. [Have a look here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e34ce/2).

Comment: What error do you get when you execute the query above?. The error message in your question refers to `timestamp`.

Answer (score 4):

Your sample select statement is trying to cast offer_start_date to timestamp not datetime.

If you do want a timestamp value from your datetime2 column you could the DatePart function to retrieve parts of the date and build it up yourself.

For example:

```
declare @date datetime2
set @date = GETUTCDATE()

select @date,
       DATEPART(hour, @date),
       DATEPART(minute, @date),
       DATEPART(second, @date)
```

MSDN reference to [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.

Not sure why you're getting that error, I've not had the same issue. Example below works fine in my 2008 Management Studio.

```
create table #temp
(
    OrderId int,
    OrderDate datetime2
)

insert into #temp
(OrderId, OrderDate)
values
(1, GetUTCDate())

select *, CAST(OrderDate as datetime)
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: +1 For more information about the infamous timestamp datatype, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied the wrong example. i tried:
SELECT CAST(offer_start_date AS datetime) FROM [ODS].[macaclient_offers]

Answer (score 2):

In my case the value was a `varchar`.

If the value is a `varchar` of `datetime2`, like `'2018-10-24 12:06:29.6112233'`, then first cast it to a `datetime2` and then to a `datetime`:

```
select cast(cast('2018-10-24 12:06:29.6112233' as datetime2) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

> convert(datetime,
>    convert(varchar(4),datepart(year,table_field ))+'-'+
>     convert(varchar(2),datepart(month,table_field ))+'-'+
>      convert(varchar(2),datepart(dd,table_field ))
>           ) 
>   when table_field is datetime2 type