# How to force entity framework to use datetime instead of datetime2 for stored procedure call?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, edmx

There is a `datetime` input in my stored procedure.

When edmx is built with database first approach, we have a

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("spInsert", ... , payDateParameter);
```

And the `payDateParameter` is defined as:

```
var payDateParameter = payDate.HasValue ?
    new ObjectParameter("PayDate", payDate.Value) :
    new ObjectParameter("PayDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
```

where `payDate` is a `DateTime?`.

The exception:

> The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'.

I understand there is a range limit in `datatime` data type. So a minimum value is added for another try.

```
var payDateParameter = payDate.HasValue ?
    new ObjectParameter("PayDate", payDate.Value) :
    new ObjectParameter("PayDate", new DateTime(1753,1,1));
```

Still the same exception.

Is there a way to force stored procedure call to use my `payDateParameter` as a `datatime` type instead of `datetime2`?

Comment: Is it possible to cast to `datetime` in the stored procedure? Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081571/how-to-cast-datetime2-as-datetime)?

Comment: I think the edmx file you created is with one version of sql server and you are trying to access another version of sql server with it. Can you check

Comment: @Krishna is correct. The edmx is created from a local database, but the production database is on a server with VPN tunnel. We are unable to reach it from local dev machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open edmx in text editor and change the below

```
<Schema Namespace="CPTTModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns:store=....
```

> The important thing to look at is the “ProviderManifestToken”
>   parameter. According to Microsoft, this parameter helps the entity
>   model function while not connected to the database, I think it also
>   helps best structure the queries it generates against the target
>   database. The tricky thing is that every time you update the data
>   model, even to move an object around in the display editor, this value
>   is updated and saved to the database it is connected to.

Comment: Perfect fix. Thank you.