# DateTime saving in Database from code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having problem saving date value in the database using EF.

In my C# code my dates are defined as:

```
DateTime ed = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(+6);
```

While in SQL Server the `date` column is defined as `DateTime`. Dates are sorted 
in `YYYY/MM/DD` format with no time.

When I try to insert values in the database with the following code:

```
t_a m = new t_a();
m.dbDate = DateTime.Today;
entity.AddTot_a(m);
entity.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error message:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

I believe it is because the value is showing as `MM/DD/YYY: HH:MM:SS`, while in the database it saves as `YYY/DD/MM`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What did not work? Show us the things you have tried.

Comment: @HanletEscaño he is already. He says he runs the code in the question and it result in an error.

Comment: He also says: "I checked other posts didnt work."

Comment: Following post had same error but I can not implement this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-sharp-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value. So the string formatting cannot be the problem.

Also: you're using .NET `DateTime` all the way - that's the way to do it, so the cause of this error must be something else.

**Guessing** from the error message, I think you might have this situation:

- you're **developing** your EF model against a SQL Server **2008** (or 2008 R2, or 2012) version database
- you're **running** your application against a SQL Server **2005** database

The problem is: if you use the EF modelling tools against a 2008 (or newer) database, it will default to using `DATETIME2` as the "date" datatype - but SQL Server **2005** doesn't have that datatype.

What you need to do is make sure that before you build your application, the `.edmx` file is opened as an XML file in Visual Studio (right-click on it in Solution Explorer, use "Open with..." and pick the XML editor), and then you find and fix this attribute in the EDMX file:

```
<Schema Namespace="MdsModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        ProviderManifestToken="2005" ....>
        ****************************
```

Make sure the `ProviderManifestToken` is set to a value of `2005`.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a really good way to set this as a property anywhere, you just have to check this every time to change something in your EDMX model file and before you build your app.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it won't let me add a comment (sorry, still kind of new to this site) so i post this as answer: Could using the [SqlDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) data type be an option for you?