# Cannot Insert Data by Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to inset data from an ASP.Net Web API application into a database using Entity Framework.  But I get an exception of:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
```

the exception happens when that method fire db.SaveChanges();
Here is the code of the post method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // db.Entry(transaction).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.Transactions.Add(transaction);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, transaction);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = transaction }));

        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Here is the model:

```
public partial class Transaction
{
    public int TrnID { get; set; }
    public string TrnSubject { get; set; }
    public int TrnCategoryID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrnDate { get; set; }
    public int TrnAccount { get; set; }
    public bool TrnType { get; set; }
    public decimal TrnAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get if you debug? What is the reason for not updating?

Comment: Aren't you trying to edit already existing item? If yes, then you should call **Attach** before the actual update.

Comment: I am trying to insert new item

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint and step though the code, what does the message in the exception say? There is a reason the database don't want to insert your item.

Comment: the exception happens when that method fire db.SaveChanges();

Comment: It is likely that you have a foreign key on one of the fields in the database. If the data being inserted to this field causes an FK violation then you can get this exception.

Comment: Until you find the inner exception as suggested, everyone is just guessing.

Comment: Yes, but if you debug, you can look at the InnerException message. In almost every case that will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: how can i get InnerException message

Comment: it's called InnerException within the exception

Comment: {"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: You should update your question with this information as it changes it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the TrnDate value is set to a value. You can print out the TrnDate value first, or place a breakpoint to see what it's value is.

This exception can be caused by inserting a null value into a non-nullable datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error for various reasons i.e Not passing proper value (or a null value) to the DateTime from your code or Date entered does not fit the date range for the type of the specified for the column.
Check what exact values are getting passed from your entities to the database.

You can refer the following post for reference:

[Stack overflow - conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
resulted in an out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-sharp-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type)