# Cannot set State to "Modified" after using Find() method. Cannot update db record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type
>   'WebLanguageTeacher.Models.MyDatabase.Word' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This
>   can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

This is how it looks like:

```
var getWordfromDB = db.Words.Find(word.ID);
word.NextReview = getWordfromDB.NextReview;
word.LastReviewed = getWordfromDB.LastReviewed;

db.Entry(word).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I'm making some changes in "Word" object. For some reasons I have to get data from database and put it again to the same object.
Without using Find() method, EntityState.Modified works, but when I placed it there, it throws this error.

How to fix that?

Comment: can you post you `Word` class details?

Comment: I can, but I think it's not the point. This is typical class with some string variables. I think this is more EF problem

Comment: if EF had a problem many people have found it earlier than you. your question details is incomplete. we can not help you without knowing the details.

Comment: You use `word`'s ID to get `getWordFromDB` but then you modify `word`. What's the point of `getWordFromDB` then (you say "for some reasons", what reasons)? And how do you get `word` in the first place?

Comment: @dotctor, WiktorZychla Here is the class and "the problem". There is as issue with DateTime, so while getting it from form I receive null DateTime values. C# gets datetime2 value, ef wants datetime value, so get an error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062192/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o

Comment: Find method first checks in datastore if the item is present else it fires query. So i think word was previously fetched and that is available in dataStore so getWordFromDB and word both  are pointing to same object. So use db.Words.First(x=>x.Id==word.ID);, It may help you

Comment: @AnkushJain, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared because of my wrong understanding of what exactly db.[class].Find() does.

I thought that it simply copies object to the variable, but it's not true. This works as something like *link* to one of the records in database. The "Word"  was somehow marked as "currently modified" so any other attempts to reach this database record was rejected.

I don't know if what I'm saying is correct, but I realized that while debugging, through "trial and error".