# Conversion of a datetime2 error while trying to save DateTime field using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am trying to save Time with entity framework. I am not really bothered about the date. I have declared my property as DateTime in Code and I am using CodeFirst.

In the xaml I use xceed TimePicker to display the Time as below

```
<Xceed:TimePicker Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Value="{Binding SelectedItem.UpdateTimer, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="LongTime" />
```

The problem is that when I run my application for the first time, The Datetime received by my property in code is '01/0/1/0001' for date followed by the time I have entered. When I try to save my context, I get this error which probably means that SQL Server does not like my date. How should I fix this?

"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

My Property code is

```
     public DateTime UpdateTimer
         {
             get
             {
                 return Data.UpdateTimer;
             }
             set
             {
                 if (value != Data.UpdateTimer)
                 {
                     Data.UpdateTimer = value;
                     OnPropertyChanged("UpdateTimer");
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with your code, it seems you send null to your property, hence the date 01/0/1/0001.

Comment: I have added my property code from View Model in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand form your code, you don't set your date it the setter of the `UpdateTimer` and then you bind it with your `TimePicker`, what the setter return to your control is probably null, that's because you get this error, try setting the value in the setter see if you still get an error, also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-sharp-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type) question see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I initialized my field with today's date which solved my problem

```
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;    
        UpdateTimer = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 5);
```