# Conversion of a datetime2 error using a nullable date column and EF 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

We are using a database first approach (SQL Server) and defined a *nullable* date column. We generated the context in Visual Studio en confirmed that `[Column(TypeName = "Date")]` was added. When we save a new record (*we confirmed that the value is either null or has a value > 01-01-2000*) we got following exception.

> Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" exception.

We looked at other SO questions and [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/229/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of-range-value) article but we could not find the real reason for this error other than changing the database column to a nullable datetime2. Is this a known restriction of EF?

Comment: the field must not be `DateTime` type but `DateTime?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type results out-of-range value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-results-out-of-range)

Comment: We tried to reproduce the described problem on another computer and could not reproduce it. Both the Code First and the Database First approach worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the `datetime` field in database is optional and value is not set. its one of the *entity-framework* architectural things.

I would recommend one to debug the issue, see if it shows the date like this `0001/1/1` and in that case initializing the field with some value or the `property` `nullable` as `DateTime` is a value-type `struct`

as you said *(we confirmed that the value is either null or between `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue`)* then the only solution one can find is this:

```
var value = values[name];
if (value is DateTime)
{
    var date = (DateTime)value;
    if (date < SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
    {
        values[name] = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
    }
    else if (date > SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value)
    {
        values[name] = SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** `SqlDateTime.MinValue != DateTime.MinValue`

In *entity framework* set the `nullable` property in the `edmx` file to `True`

[image]

Hope this helps you in any way :)