# Valid date not converting to datetime2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple table with 2 date time fields

These are setup within my objects with valid dates

However, when saving the values are getting generated by entity framework as 0001-01-01 00:00:00

What can cause this?

I am using Entity Framework Core against SQL Server 2016

Please see the image below which proves I have valid dates

I have noticed that the date is shown in USA format not sure if thats an issue?

[image]

I am not using an edmx, I have tried [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")] above the columns as well as trying with the column being both nullable and not nullable

My insert code is below

```
    using (var db = new MydbContext(connectionsString))
    {
        var rawItem = db.tblItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId== createItem.Item.ItemId);
        if (rawItem == null)
        {
            rawItem = new tblItem();
            db.tblItem.Add(rawItem);
        }

        rawItem.ItemdDateTime = message.Item.ItemDateTime;
        rawItem.ProcessedDateTime = message.Item.ProcessedDateTime;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Paul

Comment: It’s a date time column

Comment: can you post your C# call to insert

Comment: Have added it above

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-results-out-of-range

Comment: Ok there are loads of comments on this and most are very old I will take a look when I get back to the office. The strange thing is that my variable has a valid date? So I don’t understand how that can get mapped to no date which then causes this