# SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.8

I catch

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at accwf.EmployeeAddForm.SaveItem() in D:\github\accwf\accwf\ListData\EmployeeAddForm.cs:line 75
   at accwf.EmployeeAddForm.simpleButtonSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\github\accwf\accwf\ListData\EmployeeAddForm.cs:line 34
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.BaseWndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseControl.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at accwf.Program.Main() in D:\github\accwf\accwf\Program.cs:line 45

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception 2:
SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
```

object

```cs
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace accwf
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class AccountObject
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AccountObject()
        {
            this.AccountObject1 = new HashSet<AccountObject>();
            this.AccountObjectBankAccounts = new HashSet<AccountObjectBankAccount>();
            this.AccountObjectShippingAddresses = new HashSet<AccountObjectShippingAddress>();
            this.Contracts = new HashSet<Contract>();
        }
    
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AccountObjectCode { get; set; }
        public string AccountObjectName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string BirthPlace { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AgreementSalary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SalaryCoefficient { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NumberOfDependent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> InsuranceSalary { get; set; }
        public string BankAccount { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string AccountObjectGroupList { get; set; }
        public string AccountObjectGroupListCode { get; set; }
        public string CompanyTaxCode { get; set; }
        public string Tel { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PaymentTermID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MaxDebtAmount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DueTime { get; set; }
        public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> IssueDate { get; set; }
        public string IssueBy { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string ProvinceOrCity { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string WardOrCommune { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
        public string ContactMobile { get; set; }
        public string OtherContactMobile { get; set; }
        public string ContactFixedTel { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
        public string ContactAddress { get; set; }
        public bool IsVendor { get; set; }
        public bool IsCustomer { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmployee { get; set; }
        public bool AccountObjectType { get; set; }
        public bool ActiveStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OrganizationUnitID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BranchID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ReceiptableDebtAmount { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        public string AccountObjectGroupListName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string BankBranchName { get; set; }
        public string BankProvinceOrCity { get; set; }
        public string LegalRepresentative { get; set; }
        public string EInvoiceContactName { get; set; }
        public string EInvoiceContactEmail { get; set; }
        public string EInvoiceContactAddress { get; set; }
        public string EInvoiceContactMobile { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EmployeeType { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AccountObject> AccountObject1 { get; set; }
        public virtual AccountObject AccountObject2 { get; set; }
        public virtual OrganizationUnit OrganizationUnit { get; set; }
        public virtual OrganizationUnit OrganizationUnit1 { get; set; }
        public virtual PaymentTerm PaymentTerm { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AccountObjectBankAccount> AccountObjectBankAccounts { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AccountObjectShippingAddress> AccountObjectShippingAddresses { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I've seen this before with code first.  Is this here the same as your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284996/1188197 ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-results-out-of-range?rq=1

Comment: Show us your CREATE TABLE for this account table

Comment: Or is it my answer here, where there is a default or computed value and EF doesn't know about it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28880616/285795