# Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

This is my simple code for database insertion. But when am trying to insert to datetime column in the database, I got the error:

> Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I tried some marked as answers here but none of those worked for me, I am using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC.

```
public void rfrPost()
{
    nfmsdb.request_for_refund.Add(new request_for_refund
                                      {
                                          date_requested = date_requested
                                      });
    
    nfmsdb.SaveChanges();
}
```

My model in edmx:

```
public partial class request_for_refund
{
    public DateTime date_requested { get; set; }
}
```

My column datatype in the database:

```
date_requested DateTime Nullable Yes
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the datetime value getting inserted ?

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: i was looking for the value not it's format

Comment: Oh sorry "date_requested" : "2022-04-06 04:00:00",

Comment: Did you try the link that was shared? Does the problem still percist

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because the range of datetime and datetime2 is different. I think there is a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1332513/4911048).

> Both the DATETIME and DATETIME2 map to System.DateTime in .NET - you cannot really do a "conversion", since it's really the same .NET type.
>
> See the MSDN doc page:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx
>
> There are two different values for the "SqlDbType" for these two - can
> you specify those in your DataColumn definition?
>
> BUT: on SQL Server, the date range supported is quite different.
>
> DATETIME supports 1753/1/1 to "eternity" (9999/12/31), while DATETIME2
> supports 0001/1/1 through eternity.
>
> So what you really need to do is check for the year of the date - if
> it's before 1753, you need to change it to something AFTER 1753 in
> order for the DATETIME column in SQL Server to handle it.