# SqlException: Changing a datetime bus of the datetime2 data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement was terminated

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime2

When calling `_tld.SaveChanges();` I get this error:

> SqlException: Changing a datetime bus of the datetime2 data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement was terminated.

My project uses Entity Framework database-first and a SQL Server. What is this the solution for this problem?

This is my code in which I get this exception:

```
public static Result SavePendingTransactionsData(transaction[] model)
{
    Authorize authorize = new Authorize();

    using (TechLogisticsEntities _tld = new TechLogisticsEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                L_ROD_AsTwentyFourTransaction asTwentyFourTransaction = new L_ROD_AsTwentyFourTransaction();
                asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionNumber = item.transactionNumber;
                asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionType = item.transactionType;
                asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionDate = item.entryTransactionDate;
                asTwentyFourTransaction.VehiclePlate = item.VCRegistrationNumber;
                asTwentyFourTransaction.VehicleId = int.Parse(item.VCNumber);
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionAmount =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.CurrencyId =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.CurrencyCode =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.GrossAmount =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionValue =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.Unit =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionCountryName =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionCountryCode =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.TransactionLocation =
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.ObuId =
                //2 olan 
                asTwentyFourTransaction.StatusId = 1;
                //asTwentyFourTransaction.StatusCode =

                _tld.L_ROD_AsTwentyFourTransaction.Add(asTwentyFourTransaction);
                _tld.SaveChanges();
            }

            return new Result() { IsSuccess = true };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Result() { IsSuccess = false, UserMessage = ex.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `item.entryTransactionDate`?

Comment: Please show the table definition in SQL, and the matching C# definition

Comment: Probably something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-results-out-of-range