# How to check a date to make sure it is not in the future tense without dropping the app on WPF with EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datetime, try-catch

I have an app that maintains the database which contains people with their data. Like phone number, date of birth, address etc. I want to fix one of the bugs... I need to add only existing date of birth(the date must not be in the future tense and must correspond to the required format (format 01.01.0101 drops the app P.S this one is example). I know how to do these restrictions/checks and validate the data, but i have one big problem - my app drops when i throwing the exception... The try-catch construction does not help

this code checks the date of birth so that it cannot be in the future:

```
private DateTime _dateOfBirth;
public DateTime DateOfBirth
{
    get { return _dateOfBirth; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            if (DateOfBirth > DateTime.Now)
            {
                throw new Exception("Дата рождения не может быть в будущем.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка при записи в базу данных: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: I enter a date in the future and shows an error that the application will be closed for an unknown reason]
[image: First eception]
[image: Second exception]

This is the WPF app with EF. I am started learning it an dont know how to handle these exceptions..

I tried to use the try-catch construct, but it didn't help
Also tried to use a global error handler, but its not working too.

```
public App()
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += OnUnobservedTaskException;
    }

    void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Необработанное исключение: " + e.Exception.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    void OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Необработанное исключение: " + ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    void OnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Необработанное исключение: " + e.Exception.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        e.SetObserved();
    }
```

Comment: Likely that occurs when you try an save a datetime that is smaller than January 1st of 1753 or greater December 31st 9999. These are the accepted ranges for the MS-SQL-Server datatype DATETIME.
In order to fix it make sure that the date values trying to be stored are within that range (for example in the setter for "Birthday" in your Person viewmodel) or make Birthday nullable and store nulls for inappropriate input.
The default value for .NET-DateTime (DateTime.MinValue, Jan 1st 0001)  for example would already cause this exception.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-results-out-of-range Same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to set `_dateOfBirth` at all. So it is always `DateTime.MinValue` (`Jan 1st 0001 0:00:00`), which is an illegal value for MS-SQL-Server datatype `DATETIME`.

Also you don't notify by raising `PropertyChanged`.
If I were you I'd check the data input to comply to Sql-Server DATETIME value range, make the field/Property nullable - also in the DataBase, just show a MessageBox without try-catch, and raise a property change when value has been set.

```
private const DateTime _sqlServerDateMin = new DateTime (1753, 1, 1);

private DateTime? _dateOfBirth;
public DateTime? DateOfBirth
{
    get => _dateOfBirth;
    set
    {
        if (value > DateTime.Now)
        {
            // consider communicating input errors with IDataErrorInfo and Validation.ErrorTemplate
            MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка при записи в базу данных: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        if (value < _sqlServerDateMin)
        {  
            value = null;
        }
        if (!Nullable.Equals(value, _dateOfBirth))
        { 
            _dateOfBirth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
// usually in ViewModel base class:
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] propertyName = "") {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
}
```

Comment: The exception and the try catch are also really unnecessary just to show a MessageBox

Answer (score 2):

I consider it to mostly be bad form but you can handle the validation within the setter and display an error message without throwing exceptions that could crash your application.

```
private DateTime _dateOfBirth;
public DateTime DateOfBirth
{
    get { return _dateOfBirth; }
    set
    {
        DateTime tempDate = value;

        if (tempDate > DateTime.Now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Дата рождения не может быть в будущем.", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            _dateOfBirth = tempDate; // Only assign the value if it's valid.
        }
    }
}
```