# SqlDateTime.MinValue is 1753. Why?

Tags: c#, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)

In SqlDateTime.MinValue is 1753

Why the last two digits are 53? Why it is not rounded to 1700?

Anyone know the reason behind this? :)

edit: I corrected the question. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server

Comment: [It is not 1753](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) -- where did you get that value from?

Comment: I think its sql min datetime value .. [`yes Indeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx)

Comment: @Jon, I believe that's the minimum date for the datetime type in SQL server. Not to be confused with the DateTime type in the .NET framework as you mention.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers: I read (and upvoted) the answer Guillaume links to, so now I know. But the question is totally misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DateTime.MinValue` is `01/01/0001 00:00:00`.

As for why `SqlDateTime.MinValue` is in 1753, that's answered here: [SqlDateTime.MinValue != DateTime.MinValue, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805770/sqldatetime-minvalue-datetime-minvalue-why/805773) and here: [What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)