# Difference between FloatToStr(Now) in Delphi and Cast(GETDATE() as float) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, date

Why is there a difference between the conversion of a date in Delphi and SQL Server with these commands:

**SQL Server :**

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)
```

**Delphi :**

```
writeln(floattostr(now));
```

**Example: For today**

```
SQL Server = 40871.431264506 
Delphi     = 40873.4333729861
```

Why are the two results different?

Comment: Can you show the different results you are getting?  Is there a specific problem you're having?  The context may make it easier for someone to help you out.

Comment: for to day:

(SQL Server)
Select Cast(GetDate() as Float) : 40871.431264506


(Delphi)
Writeln(FloatToStr(Now)); : 40873.4333729861

Comment: I've added the example to your question for the sake of readability.

Comment: SQL Server drops milliseconds from any time sent to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because many languages have different ways of dealing with dates internally. They may or may not store them internally as a float, and may also start counting at different "starting" dates. For instance, Delphi starts at 12/30/1899 (a TDateTime of 0).

See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805770/sqldatetime-minvalue-datetime-minvalue-why).