# DataTable doesn't accept DateTime field from MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a field DateTime for default its "null" but when my datatable try to read this field
this is what happens

> Não correspondência entre o tipo de valor e o tipo de colunaNão foi possível guardar ><01/01/0001 00:00:00> na coluna dh_cadastro. O tipo previsto é MySqlDateTime.

Mismatch between the type of value and type of column.Not possible be saved <01/01/0001 00:00:00> dh_cadastro column. The type expected is provided MySqlDateTime.

Comment: What is the valid datetime range in MySql?  I know SQL Server's is not the same as System.DateTime.

Comment: I think that it might be caused by your default value - DateTime is a value type, so it can't be null. Try using DateTime.MinValue instead.

Comment: The value of `DateTime.MinValue` is different than MySQL's minimum representable `MySqlDateTime` value.  You're seeing an error from the database, so you'd need to check against `MySqlDateTime.MinValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using null as a default value use a nullable DateTime object (`DateTime?`)

A regular DateTime cannot be null since it is a value type.

If you are getting errors with dates from the database, do a update to make sure there are no `'0000-00-00'` dates. Update these to be 0001-01-01 to align with .NET's `DateTime.MinValue`

Also see [SqlDateTime.MinValue != DateTime.MinValue, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805770/sqldatetime-minvalue-datetime-minvalue-why) for a review of the DateTime.MinValue issue between MySQL and .NET

Comment: I Found out the error...
The fields of  birth_date are "0000-00-00" But when I ctrlC + CtrlV on it... when I past what I copy, its "24/12/2012, 25/04/2011"... Its normal dates... What the hell? I guess it's demonic stuff... any help ? Thanks