# Update error with DateTime fields

Tags: c#, datetime, dataset

I have a *method* which takes in some *parameters*, among which there are three `DateTime` fields *(populated from the Web Form)*.

The *method* uses an automatically generated `TableAdapter` and `DataSet` to add a new record onto a table. After the *`Table.Add[newRow]`* statement, we call the *`Dataset.Update(Table)`* statement to persist the addition onto the database.

While this works as expected for almost all cases, it sometimes gives an error:
*`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
The statement has been terminated.`*.

Does anyone have a clue as to what may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/2c0975dd-bc9c-454f-8583-af74d1cd7141)

> The date datatype can hold dates from Jan 1 of year 1 thru Dec 31,
>   9999.  The datetime datatype can only hold dates from Jan 1, 1753 thru Dec 31, 9999.  So you must have dates in your table with values of
>   less than Jan 1, 1753.

Since `DateTime` is a struct, hence always has a value(`DateTime.MinValue`), another possible reason is that the `DateTime` could not be parsed successfully.

So you could check before you insert if the `DateTime` is in a valid range of `SqlDateTime`:

```
DateTime darkAge = new DateTime(1111, 1, 1);
if (darkAge >= SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value && darkAge <= SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value)
{
    // we're not gettting here since the dark age was before 1753 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response; it came a few minutes before I eventually cracked this, but you are on the right path. I really had to dive into the SQL statements as this was eventually an SQL issue, not a c# issue. Turns out the Insert was firing a trigger on the table which was running an update statement which was in turn using a custom function to get the date part from a DateTime; for this particular instance a record was manually added with a wrong date (0202-12-28 as opposed to 2012-12-28), and the function trying to extract the date part was throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's becoz SQL DateTime and DotNet DateTime vary in allowed ranges.

[SqlDateTime.MinValue != DateTime.MinValue, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805770/sqldatetime-minvalue-datetime-minvalue-why)